# Can iOS Kamcord SDK be used to record screens of apps other than games?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, uiwebview, screen-capture

I am looking for a solution to record the screen of my app - especially an online video. Initially I used this link to implement this:
http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673

This does record everything selected in the view however the youtube player shows up as a black screen. After research I came across the Kamcord library used by games.

1. Anyone know if this can be used to record non-game app views - especially online videos embedded in UIWebView?
2. Do you know why the video in a uiwebview is treated differently? Is it using open-gl?

Comment: Do you want the recording to be a feature of your app or do you need to record your app for other reasons?

Comment: it's one of the features of the app to be able to record any webpage. right now videos embedded in the webpage show up as a black screen. @rmaddy

Comment: Sadly the service 'latest' version is view only. I secretly hope they find a way to make money and bring it back. It was a great idea, lofty, and for a young group of people to be so disruptive to the likes of recording services like EveryPlay I was proud to be a member of that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the answer your hoping for. But this may be helpful to someone looking to do this in the future.

The current version of Kamcord 1.9 does not support any recording. Kamcord is moving into the live stream hosting business. Version 1.7 is still obtainable via [github](https://github.com/kamcord/kamcord-ios-sdk) Official support is supposed to end August 24th 2015, but I haven't had a reply back, even for questions about the new version for weeks now, a week before official close.

The online implementation documentation was kept on their website and I when I asked for the 1.7 documents I was told they "did not have them" since no backup was kept. I suggested they look into source control systems. You can get some of the [older iOS documents from the way back machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150509053701/https://docs.kamcord.com/documents/platform/ios/getting-started/) (please consider donating) but the Android documents are not to be found (nor did it do basic things like let you control video length on Android.)

Comment: You may have a very hard time finding help with this given the last two weeks trend, over the last two years Kamcord has been nothing but brilliant in the support department. This is not the case this month. There is utter silence coming out of the support email (just my experience! maybe not indicative of anyone else's.)